# SVG image not displaying properly in HTML webpage

Tags: inkscape, svg, html

I'm trying to insert an svg image that I created in Inkscape into my html web page but for some reason I can't get it to render correctly.

Is there some sort of extra exporting step to get an SVG image to html page?

[image: Example img:]

What its supposed to look like
[image: example2]

Comment: Can you add a link to the actual page?

Answer (score 0):

Save as optimized SVG.
In particular, in Illustrator, **don't** use "Save as", **use** File > Export > Export for Screens .... Then select SVG as format .

Answer (score 0):

Set the screen width and height to 100% as given below:

```
<html>
  <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1550 1200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <!---Your code here-->
  </svg>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Camilla said, export it as screen. I tried so many ways the svg still not show up, and now is working fine after I export it in illustrator as screen

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so I figured it out. If google brought you here hi, post a comment to let me know ^.^

This tutorial was very helpful, look at section 2.2

http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Using_SVG_with_HTML5_tutorial

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without looking at your files and your answer doesn't tell what you did to solve it. Self-answering is fine but you have to comply with the guidelines on [help]. Can you please fix both? Otherwise the question will probably be deleted and this answer will get downvoted.